# Background Image not showing in Internet Explorer at the end of an animation

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, background-image

I've tried a few things on this, like switching out the svg for a png, I've stared at my formatting and can't see anything wrong with it, I'm not coming up with anything. I'm wondering if the CSS animation is maybe interfering with it somehow?

Here's the [website](https://www.pottertour.co.uk/privates.html) with it working in other browsers, on Internet Explorer 11 the circle just remains a yellow circle at the end of the animation.

```css
#rosette {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: crimson;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  animation: rosette-anim 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  content: "";
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: rgb(51, 55, 56);
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: rotateY(0.5turn);
}

@keyframes rosette-anim {
  95% {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(51, 55, 56);
    height: 137px;
    width: 142px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    transform: rotateY(2turn);
    top: 4px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    height: 137px;
    width: 142px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    transform: rotateY(3turn);
    background: rgb(164, 132, 60) url('https://www.pottertour.co.uk/imagesAwards/lux-life-award-transparent-min.svg');
    background-size: 139px 100px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 4px;
    right: 26px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rosette"></div>
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, IE will not let you animate the `background-image` property. Try animating the `background-position` property instead :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation and transition for pseudo-elements is [not supported by IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_after_animation_and_transition_support). You could create `<div>` and use ID to write CSS for it and avoid using pseudo. The sample code is like below:

```css
#rosette {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: crimson;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  animation: rosette-anim 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  content: "";
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: rgb(51, 55, 56);
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: rotateY(0.5turn);
}

@keyframes rosette-anim {
  95% {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(51, 55, 56);
    height: 137px;
    width: 142px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    transform: rotateY(2turn);
    top: 4px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    height: 137px;
    width: 142px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    transform: rotateY(3turn);
    background: rgb(164, 132, 60);
    background-size: 139px 100px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 4px;
    right: 26px;
  }
}

#before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 90px solid rgb(164, 132, 60);
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  top: 95px;
  right: 80px;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) rotate(-140deg);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: change 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 90px solid rgb(164, 132, 60);
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  top: 95px;
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) rotate(140deg);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: change 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes change {
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rosette"><img src="https://www.pottertour.co.uk/imagesAwards/lux-life-award-transparent-min.svg" id="award" alt="My private Harry Potter tours won Lux Life magazine&#39;s award for best pop culture tour Edinburgh, they anointed it &#39;Truly magical&#39;, bless them."
  /></div>
<div id="before"></div>
<div id="after"></div>
```

Result in IE11:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou @YuZhou , I hadn't thought of moving the Rosetta fins to their own divs rather than pseudo elements of the rosette's yellow circle.  That really crystallises IE for me, move everything to it's own divs.  You've been a great help, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I used `::before` pseudo element for background-image and I wrote another keyframe animation for animate `::before` element. This works in IE11.

```css
#rosette {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: crimson;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  animation: rosette-anim 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: rgb(51, 55, 56);
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: rotateY(0.5turn);
}

#rosette:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://www.pottertour.co.uk/imagesAwards/lux-life-award-transparent-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  animation: rosette-before 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes rosette-anim {
  95% {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(51, 55, 56);
    height: 137px;
    width: 142px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    transform: rotateY(2turn);
    top: 4px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    height: 137px;
    width: 142px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    transform: rotateY(3turn);
    background-color: rgb(164, 132, 60);
    z-index: 1;
    top: 4px;
    right: 26px;
  }
}

@keyframes rosette-before {
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rosette"></div>
```